# Is There a Algorithm or Library that can Detect Motion Blur in Images?

Tags: image-processing

Anyone know of an algorithm that can return fuzzy true/false to if a image has motion blur / camera shake in a image?

Ideally it would be particular to *motion* blur, as lots of the images in the set might have  blurred ([Bokeh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh)) backgrounds.

A language preference would be C, Perl, Shell Utility, or Python, but I'm open to anything really.

With my current knowledge of Math / Programming, I don't think I really have a hope of writing such an algorithm, only using one that takes some parameters...

Comment: If possible, please mark some answer as accepted. At moment it is unclear if they fit for purpose or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Discrete wavelet transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform) is a useful tool in such detection. [Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~htong/pdf/ICME04_tong.pdf) is a paper from Carnegie Mellon School of Computer Science on detecting and quantifying blur in images by using the DWT. For a binary decision, you threshold the amount to a desired level and everything above that has blur.

Comment: This is handy, but the paper explicitly says "It is effective for both Out-of-focus blur and Linear-motion blur", which means it's not much use for detecting motion blur in particular...

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder Out-of-focus blur is not directional, whereas linear-motion blur is. You can run a Principal Component Analysis to obtain the eigenvalues of the blur's characteristic edge points' direction vectors and assess the strength of the predominant one. If it's beyond a certain threshold,  you can conclude that the blur is directional, thus linear motion blur.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this, maybe one of the imaging gurus here has a much better answer. Anyways...

My first shot would be to have a frequency analysis of the image (read: 2d fourier transform). Then define a threshold for the high frequencies (i.e. fast changes from one pixel to the next) for true/false. Motion blur filters the high frequencies out. Your mileage may vary, e.g. a completely black picture will have no high frequencies although it is not blurred. Depending on the lens and aperture used, parts of the image may be blurry because they are in the background. I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all solution here.

Comment: How would this distinguish between Bokeh blur and motion blur?

Answer (score 1):

To detect blurriness, you can convolve grayscale image with laplacian kernel and calculate the variance. Focused images should have high variance and blur images should have lower variance. Below is the code to do so :

```
def is_blur(image) :
   """
   This function convolves a grayscale image with
   laplacian kernel and calculates its variance.
   """

   thresold = #Some value you need to decide

   #Laplacian kernel
   laplacian_kernel = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,-4,1],[0,1,0]])
   laplacian_kernel = tf.expand_dims(laplacian_kernel, -1)
   laplacian_kernel = tf.expand_dims(laplacian_kernel, -1)
   laplacian_kernel = tf.cast(laplacian_kernel, tf.float32)

   #Convolving image with laplacian kernel
   new_img = tf.nn.conv2d(image, laplacian_kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
                          padding="SAME")

   #Calculating variance
   img_var = tf.math.reduce_variance(new_img)

   if img_var < thresold :
      return True
   else :
      return False
```

This function takes a grayscale image as input and it should be a 4-dim tensor as tf.nn.conv2d accepts a 4-d tensor. Below is the code to load image :

```
image_string = tf.io.read_file(ImagePath)
#decoding image
image = tf.image.decode_png(image_string, channels=3)
#Converting image to grayscale
image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
# This will convert to float values in [0, 1]
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
#Reshaping image since conv2d accepts a 4-d tensor.
image = tf.reshape(image, shape=[1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 1])
```

The thresold should be set very carefully. If set too low, it can declare a blur image as focused and if set too high, then it will miss classify a focused image as blurred. A better way is to calculate the blurriness of each image and then decide by plotting a distplot.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Richardson-Lucy Algorithm. It's mostly used for blind de-convolution, but as you know that it's motion blur you need to remove, the RL Algorithms should take fewer iterations to compute a workable reconstruction.